# regex to exclude values inside double quotes(") in tableau and SQL DB

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is some sample data:

```
Customer node "4142" is cancelled as at 02/02/2010..
```

And here is the output expected:

```
Customer node is cancelled
```

Values between quotes should be excluded and print till a particular word.  In this example it should print until `cancelled`.

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using, as the answer may be highly DB dependent.

Comment: Oracle Database. And i need the pattern to be executed in both SQL and Tableau

Comment: Sorry, but the answer you get for Oracle probably won't work right away on Tableau and other databases.

Comment: May j get both the answers (SQL & Tabkeau)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, 'cancelled') - 1),
                      '(".*")\s',
                      '') AS new_col
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Untested, but it should work, at least with your sample data.

Comment: Yes its working . but while i use this expression in tableau REGEXP_REPLACE([Col_name],'(".*")\s',""), i'm confused about where to insert a particular string(ex:cancelled)

Comment: Give your new question a chance, hopefully someone will answer it.  I don't know Tableau.